# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1 in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm making project using recyclerview. When I add this statement to adapter:

`itemView.optionText.text=data.options[adapterPosition].description`

It throws a *java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1*

The code:

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

I aslo add model class to post.

I dont know what reason make this problem.

```
   internal class CartItemRecyclerAdapter(var context: Context, var cartItems: ArrayList<ViewCartdocs>,  var listener: CartItemListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CartItemRecyclerAdapter.Holder>() {

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): Holder {
            var view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cart_item_list, parent, false)
            return Holder(view)
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Holder, position: Int) {

             holder.bind(cartItems[position].cartdocs, context)
            holder.checkbox.isChecked=cartItems[position].selected

            holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null)

            holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
                if (isChecked) {
                    holder.checkbox.background = holder.checkbox.context.getDrawable(R.drawable.check_box_active_cs)
                } else {
                    holder.checkbox.background = holder.checkbox.context.getDrawable(R.drawable.check_box_no)
                    }
                    listener.onCheckboxChanged(position, isChecked)
            }

}

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return cartItems.count()
        }

            inner class Holder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

            fun bind(data: Cartdocs, context: Context) {
            val dec = DecimalFormat("##,000")
            itemView.titleText.text = data.title
            itemView.priceText.text = dec.format(data.price).toString() 
            itemView.textViewItemNumer.text = data.amount.toString()
            itemView.pointValueText.text = dec.format(data.point).toString() + "P"
            itemView.optionText.text= data.options[adapterPosition].description
            Glide.with(context).load(data.mainImage).into(imageView)

            } } } }
```

```
data class Cartdocs(
    @SerializedName("id")
    var id:String?=null,
    @SerializedName("title")
    var title:String?=null,
    @SerializedName("stock")
    var stock:Int?=null,
    @SerializedName("mainImage")
    var mainImage:String?=null,
    @SerializedName("amount")
    var amount:Int?=null,
    @SerializedName("added")
    var added:String?=null,
    @SerializedName("options")
    var options:ArrayList<cartOptions>,
    var unitPoint:Int?=null,
    @SerializedName("totalPrice")
    var totalPrice:Int?=null,
    @SerializedName("totalPoint")
    var totalPoint:Int?=null
)


data class cartOptions(

    var id:String?=null,

    var description:String?=null
)
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: It would help us to know which line of the code corresponds with the error. You can look at the stack trace and it will tell you the line number and you can mark it with a comment in your code above.

Comment: thank u for u r comment. error response code : holder.bind(cartItems[position].cartdocs, context) ,itemView.optionText.text= data.options[adapterPosition].description

Comment: Could you please post the Model class `Cartdocs`

Comment: Sure. If I will not add this code : itemView.optionText.text= data.options[adapterPosition].description. no have error anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is - You are accessing inner array or inner list of items.

You are returning (cartItems.count())

```
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return cartItems.count()
}
```

For bind function you are passing data from - **cartItems[position].cartdocs**

Inside bind function you are accessing **data.options[adapterPosition]**

above line works like - **cartItems[position].cartdocs.options[adapterPosition]**

So here **adapterPosition** not match with **data.options** list size

If you need, you can combine ArrayList of cartOptions as a single string

```
var descriptions = ""

for ((index, option) in data.options.withIndex()) {
    descriptions += option.description

    if (index != (data.options.size - 1)) {
        descriptions += ", "
    }
}

itemView.optionText.text= descriptions
```

Please try this inside bind function. If still you are facing the problem please let me know in the comments section. I am happy to help.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: thank u for u r comment ,I just add data class to post. so How can I solve it ?

Comment: Thank u so much . it is going well.